# Rviz 2d Nav goal tool

Tags: ros, rviz, 2d-nav-goal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Every time that I have to use the 2d Nav goal tool in rviz, I need to first click on it and then on the map. Once I have clicked on the map the tool/mouse pointer turns back to "interact" tool. This means if I have to use it again I need to go back to the toolbar and select it again on the 2D Nav Goal and so on.

Does someone knows if I can change that (i.e. to give 2d nav goal without the need to select the tool again and again) , preferably without messing with the rviz source code? For example the tool "Publish Point" has a property "single click" that you can change in the tools property menu, but I cannot find something similar for the 2d Nav Goal.

thanks,
Manolis

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187441/rviz-2d-nav-goal-tool/) by [Manolis Chiou](https://answers.ros.org/users/18907/manolis-chiou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2014-07-22

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-10-26**:
You can press `g` to go into goal mode. I usually just do `g`, `click`, `g`, `click`, ... over and over again. Otherwise you'll have to modify the rviz source code.

**Comment by [Manolis Chiou](https://answers.ros.org/users/18907/manolis-chiou/) on 2015-10-26**:
I am doing some experiments with human robot operators and g -> click -> g -> click , will affect the results. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are a few changes in rviz source code that allow for  "single click" property to be added or deactivated in the 2d Nav Goal. You can either use rviz from [my rviz repo](https://github.com/ManolisCh/rviz.git) or do the following changes yourself. Note that when you apply the changes you need to go in rviz window, panels -> tool properties -> 2d nav goal and change the property "single click":

***1)  in src -> rviz -> default plug in -> tools -> goal tool.cpp :***

add the includes:

```
#include "rviz/properties/bool_property.h"
#include <OgrePlane.h>
#include <OgreRay.h>
#include <OgreSceneNode.h>
#include <OgreViewport.h>
#include "rviz/geometry.h"
#include "rviz/ogre_helpers/arrow.h"
#include "rviz/viewport_mouse_event.h"
#include "rviz/load_resource.h"
#include "rviz/render_panel.h"
```

add in line 50 after the topic_property_ and inside the GoalTool():

```
 auto_deactivate_property_ = new BoolProperty( "Single click", true, "Switch away from this tool after one click.", getPropertyContainer(), SLOT( updateAutoDeactivate() ), this );
```

add in line 59 inside the void GoalTool::onInitialize():

```
// THIS IS FOR ARROW SIZE TUNING
    // DELETED PoseTool::onInitialize();
    arrow_ = new Arrow( scene_manager_, NULL, 0.25f, 0.07f, 0.15f, 0.2f ); // ADDED
    arrow_->setColor( 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f ); // ADDED
    arrow_->getSceneNode()->setVisible( false ); // ADDED
```

add in line 67 after the topic_property_ = new StringProperty() :

```
void GoalTool::updateAutoDeactivate()  {  }
```

in in line 85 after the void GoalTool::onPoseSet() function:

```
// ADD THE WHOLE FUNCTION
int GoalTool::processMouseEvent( ViewportMouseEvent& event )
{
  int flags = 0;

  if( event.leftDown() )
  {
    ROS_ASSERT( state_ == Position );

    Ogre::Vector3 intersection;
    Ogre::Plane ground_plane( Ogre::Vector3::UNIT_Z, 0.0f );
    if( getPointOnPlaneFromWindowXY( event.viewport,
                                     ground_plane,
                                     event.x, event.y, intersection ))
    {
      pos_ = intersection;
      arrow_->setPosition( pos_ );

      state_ = Orientation;
      flags |= Render;
    }
  }
  else if( event.type == QEvent::MouseMove && event.left() )
  {
    if( state_ == Orientation )
    {
      //compute angle in x-y plane
      Ogre::Vector3 cur_pos;
      Ogre::Plane ground_plane( Ogre::Vector3::UNIT_Z, 0.0f );
      if( getPointOnPlaneFromWindowXY( event.viewport,
                                       ground_plane,
                                       event.x, event.y, cur_pos ))
      {
        double angle = atan2( cur_pos.y - pos_.y, cur_pos.x - pos_.x );

        arrow_->getSceneNode()->setVisible( true );

        //we need base_orient, since the arrow goes along the -z axis by default (for historical reasons)
        Ogre::Quaternion orient_x = Ogre::Quaternion( Ogre::Radian(-Ogre::Math::HALF_PI), Ogre::Vector3::UNIT_Y );

        arrow_->setOrientation( Ogre::Quaternion( Ogre::Radian(angle), Ogre::Vector3::UNIT_Z ) * orient_x );

        flags |= Render;
      }
    }
  }
  else if( event.leftUp() )
  {
    if( state_ == Orientation )
    {
      //compute angle in x-y plane
      Ogre::Vector3 cur_pos;
      Ogre::Plane ground_plane( Ogre::Vector3::UNIT_Z, 0.0f );
      if( getPointOnPlaneFromWindowXY( event.viewport,
                                       ground_plane,
                                       event.x, event.y, cur_pos ))
      {
        double angle = atan2( cur_pos.y - pos_.y, cur_pos.x - pos_.x );

        onPoseSet(pos_.x, pos_.y, angle);
        if ( auto_deactivate_property_->getBool() )
        {
        flags |= (Finished|Render);
        }
         else if (!auto_deactivate_property_->getBool())
        {
            state_ = Position;
            arrow_->getSceneNode()->setVisible( false );
        } // ADDED TILL HERE

      }
    }
  }
  return flags;
}
```

2. ***in src -> rviz -> default plug in -> tools -> goal tool.h :***

add in line 39  after # include "rviz/default_plugin/tools/pose_tool.h"

```
# include <QObject>
```

add in line 46 after class StringProperty :

```
class BoolProperty;
```

add in line 58 after virtual void onInitialize(); :

```
virtual int processMouseEvent( ViewportMouseEvent& event ); // ADDED
```

add in line 65 after: Void updateTopic():

```
void updateAutoDeactivate();
```

add in line 73 after StringProperty* topic_property_; :

```
protected: 
  BoolProperty* auto_deactivate_property_;
```

---

Originally posted by [Manolis Chiou](https://answers.ros.org/users/18907/manolis-chiou/) with karma: 70 on 2015-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-10-26**:
Why not produce a diff and make a pull request to rviz? https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/pulls

**Comment by [Manolis Chiou](https://answers.ros.org/users/18907/manolis-chiou/) on 2015-10-28**:
I will do that once I got some time to tidy up the code  :)